# remove 'this field is required' text above django form

Tags: python, django

I cannot remove bullet points saying 'this field is required' above my django form (see picture). I have been through other questions and tried setting `form.auto_id = False`,  `form.use_required_attribute = False` and `form.label_suffix = ""` I am not sure what attribute of the form is causing this to appear so don't know what to change. I couldn't find the answer in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-configuring-label)

the .view function is

```
def new_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WikiSubmitForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # data cleaning?
            Title = form.cleaned_data["Title"]
            Body = form.cleaned_data["Body"]

            if Title in util.list_entries():
                return HttpResponse("This wiki page already exists") 
            else:
                util.save_entry(title=Title, content=Body)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("wiki/"+ Title) #would be better to make this not hardcoded!
    else:
        form = WikiSubmitForm(request.POST)
        # form.use_required_attribute = False
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/new_or_edit_page.html", {
            "new": True,
            "form": form
        })
```

The HTML file, called new_or_edit_page.html is:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>
        {% if new %}
            <h1>New page</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1>Edit page for {{ Title }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
    </h1>
{% if new %}
    <form action="{% url 'new_page' %}", method="POST">
{% else %} 
    <form action="{% url 'edit' Title %}", method="POST">
{% endif %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            {{ form }}
        </div>

        <input type="submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

[image: 'this field is required' text]

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: By default, browsers may apply their own validation on these fields, which may be stricter than Django’s validation. So Is this coming from HTML5 input types and browser validation?? If yes try to disable this behavior, set the novalidate attribute on the form tag As <form action="{% url 'new_page' %}", method="POST" novalidate> in your html file.

Comment: At you model, the setting `title/content = CharField(null=True, blank=True)` doesn´t work? At your model-form have you tried setting `title/content = forms.CharField(required=False)` ?

Answer (score 0):

So, in your forms.py you will have a field **title** and another field **body** lets say defined as follows :-

```
from django import forms

class WikiSubmitForm(forms.Forms):
    title = forms.CharFiled(label="Wiki Title", required=True)
    body = forms.CharFiled(label="Wiki Body", required=True)
```

The form fields like CharFiled, IntegerFiled et Cetra have a parameter called ***widget*** which can be used to define HTML properties like **class, name, id**, et Cetra.

You can define your HTML properties using this widget parameter as follows :-

```
from django import forms

class WikiSubmitForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Wiki title", required=False,
                           widget= forms.TextInput
                           (attrs={
                               'class': 'wiki-title',
                               'name': 'WikiTitle',
                               'placeholder':'Enter Wiki title',
                               'required': 'True'
                            }))

    body = forms.CharField(label="Wiki Body", required=False,
                           widget= forms.TextInput
                           (attrs={
                               'class': 'wiki-body',
                               'name': 'WikiBody',
                               'placeholder':'Wiki Body',
                               'required': 'True'
                            }))
```

This will not only hide the **This field is required** text but will show the usual JS pop-up below if the user tries to submit an empty, field.

Now you can also implement CSS with class and id in your HTML page.